# iOS Flutter XCode : Module 'file_picker' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I ran the app nothing wrong happened, but when i tried to Archive, it has an error

```
Module 'file_picker' not found
```

Here's where the error happened

```
#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h>)
#import <file_picker/FilePickerPlugin.h>
#else
@import file_picker;
#endif
```

it was at `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue and no information I can find fixes it.